# Android - Already have a pending vsync event

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I have three services.

`MorningNotification`, `DinnerNotification`, `EveningNotification`

And I have this code to init them:

```
morning_notification = new Intent();
    morning_notification.setClass(this, MorningNotification.class);

    dinner_notification = new Intent();
    dinner_notification.setClass(this, DinnerNotification.class);

    evening_notification = new Intent();
    evening_notification.setClass(this, EveningNotification.class);
```

After that I use them like this:

```
    ... 
    /* Запуск сервера */
                        startService(morning_notification);
    ...
 ... 
    /* Запуск сервера */
                        startService(dinner_notification);
    ...
 ... 
    /* Запуск сервера */
                        startService(evening_notification);
    ...
```

But, the problem is that only **MorningNotification** service is working. But I need to start all three.

I have this log:

```
 W/Choreographer﹕ Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
12-09 09:35:03.025  12961-12961/ru.mentalcalculation E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12-09 09:35:07.895  12961-12961/ru.mentalcalculation W/Choreographer﹕ Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
12-09 09:35:07.895  12961-12961/ru.mentalcalculation E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12-09 09:35:12.845  12961-12961/ru.mentalcalculation W/Choreographer﹕ Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
12-09 09:35:12.845  12961-12961/ru.mentalcalculation E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant start the three services at the same time. I suggest you finish with morning intent before you call the next. This is to avoid uncontrolled branching which might go out of control. You may check:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html